# How to read a file using multiple threads in Java when a high throughput(3GB/s) file system is available

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, io

I understand that for a normal Spindle Drive system, reading files using multiple threads is inefficient.

**This is a different case, I have a high-throughput file systems available to me, which provides read speeds up to 3GB/s, with 196 CPU cores and 2TB RAM**

A single threaded Java program reads the file with maximum 85-100 MB/s, so I have potential to get better than single thread. I have to read files as big as 1TB in size and I have enough RAM to load it.

Currently I use the following or something similar, but need to write something with multi-threading to get better throughput:

Java 7 Files: 50 MB/s

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```

Java commons-io: 48 MB/s

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), "utf-8");
```

The same with guava: 45 MB/s

```
List<String> lines = Files.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Java Scanner Class: Very Slow

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

*I want to be able to load the file and build the same ArrayList, in the correct sorted sequence, as fast as possible.*

There is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226819/java-i-o-unexpected-performance-difference-between-sequentially-and-concurrentl) that reads similar, but it is actually different, because of :
The question is discussing about systems where multi-threaded file I/O is physically impossible to be efficient, but due to technological advancements, we now have systems that are designed to support high-throughput I/O , and so the limiting factor is CPU/SW , which can be overcome by multi-threading the I/O.

The other question does not answer how to write code to multi-thread I/O.

Comment: Divide the file into N chunks, read each chunk in a thread, then merge them in order.  Beware of lines that cross chunk boundaries.

Comment: Your memory bus is probably only around 500 Mbytes/s to 800 Mbytes/s so there's no way you can use all of that bandwidth.  What kind of system is this?

Comment: @markspace: The storage is networked and connected with 10Gigabit Ethernet port. I have written programs in C , that read files in at 1GB/s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Here is the solution to read a single file with multiple threads.**

*Divide the file into N chunks, read each chunk in a thread, then merge them in order. Beware of lines that cross chunk boundaries. It is the basic idea as suggested by user 
[slaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)*

Bench-marking below implementation of multiple-threads for a single 20 GB file:

1 Thread : 50 seconds : 400 MB/s

2 Threads: 30 seconds : 666 MB/s

**4 Threads: 20 seconds : 1GB/s**

8 Threads: 60 seconds : 333 MB/s

Equivalent Java7 readAllLines() : 400 seconds : 50 MB/s

Note: This may only work on systems that are designed to support high-throughput I/O , and not on usual personal computers

```
package filereadtests;

import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.Math.toIntExact;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class FileRead implements Runnable
{

private FileChannel _channel;
private long _startLocation;
private int _size;
int _sequence_number;

public FileRead(long loc, int size, FileChannel chnl, int sequence)
{
    _startLocation = loc;
    _size = size;
    _channel = chnl;
    _sequence_number = sequence;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Reading the channel: " + _startLocation + ":" + _size);

        //allocate memory
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(_size);

        //Read file chunk to RAM
        _channel.read(buff, _startLocation);

        //chunk to String
        String string_chunk = new String(buff.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Done Reading the channel: " + _startLocation + ":" + _size);

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//args[0] is path to read file
//args[1] is the size of thread pool; Need to try different values to fing sweet spot
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
    FileChannel channel = fileInputStream.getChannel();
    long remaining_size = channel.size(); //get the total number of bytes in the file
    long chunk_size = remaining_size / Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //file_size/threads

    //Max allocation size allowed is ~2GB
    if (chunk_size > (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5))
    {
        chunk_size = (Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5);
    }

    //thread pool
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

    long start_loc = 0;//file pointer
    int i = 0; //loop counter
    while (remaining_size >= chunk_size)
    {
        //launches a new thread
        executor.execute(new FileRead(start_loc, toIntExact(chunk_size), channel, i));
        remaining_size = remaining_size - chunk_size;
        start_loc = start_loc + chunk_size;
        i++;
    }

    //load the last remaining piece
    executor.execute(new FileRead(start_loc, toIntExact(remaining_size), channel, i));

    //Tear Down
    executor.shutdown();

    //Wait for all threads to finish
    while (!executor.isTerminated())
    {
        //wait for infinity time
    }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    fileInputStream.close();
}

}
```

Comment: what is toIntExact doing here. please explain.

Comment: @SunnyGupta toIntExact is used to safely cast from long to an int without losing any information. Refer this link<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java>

Comment: When I use the same code, the `channel` that sent over to new thread will have `BufferUnderflowException` when I try to get byte from the ByteBuffer

Answer (score -3):

You should first try the java 7 Files.readAllLines:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```

Using a multi threaded approach is probably not a good option as it will force the filesystem to perform random reads (which is never a good thing on a file system)

Comment: The above code/function reads at 65MB/s , I tested it. It is not good enough

Comment: Update , the average read speed is actually 50 MB/s with the above function